# How do I compress a video with GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, compression, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImage to crop existing videos with the GPUImage crop filter.  A 5 second video is currently exporting with with a size of 3.5MB @ 320x320.  I need to get this below 1MB, but I'm not sure how to use GPUImage to compress the video.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework You can easily resize the image.

Comment: could you please share code where you  apply crop to video and save in square resolution. I tried something like this:
    movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480, 640)];
    
    GPUImageCropFilter *cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 480 / 640.0f)];[videoCamera addTarget:cropFilter];[cropFilter addTarget:filterView];
   But saved movie is stretched and not cropped as it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this update:
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/pull/310

There is an initializer which accepts output settings dictionary

```
- (id)initWithMovieURL:(NSURL *)newMovieURL size:(CGSize)newSize fileType:(NSString *)newFileType outputSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)outputSettings;
```

Comment: You can replace the link with code and accept your own answer here :)

Comment: can you add full of code how can you set actul URL and how to get compress url